# Validate that a JSON request is an array, not an object

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to come up with a way, using the native Laravel validator, to require that only a JSON array is passed as the root of the request.  Incoming JSON data is automatically converted to a PHP array, regardless of whether the root was a JSON object or array, making this difficult.  Laravel's validator is only built to validate values of an array, not the array itself.

For example, I want to make sure that this is accepted:

```
[
  {
    "field": "value"
  }
]
```

But this is rejected:

```
{
  "anything": {
    "field": "value"
  }
}
```

A simple validation rule such as `'*.field' => 'required|string'` works fine for the *contents* of the array, but cannot distinguish between the two.  I thought perhaps I could do `'' => 'required|array'` but this fails as it just tries to validate an array value with an empty string for its key, which is a valid thing (thanks, PHP!).

The best solution I have come up with is to manually test the raw, encoded JSON data with a regex, but this seems crude and can't be integrated with the Validator as far as I can tell.  Another potential option is checking `Arr::isAssoc(request()->all())`, but again this has the same issue.

The following validator rule is a very hacky solution, which still doesn't catch an object containing keys that are strings of integers because for some reason the validator converts the array indexes (what it considers an "attribute") to strings.

```php
'*' => [static function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    if (!ctype_digit($attribute)) {
        $fail('Request must be an array, not an object.');
    }
}],
```